# GetDWORDValue method of the StdRegProv class "path"

Tags: vbscript, registry, 64-bit, windows-installer

Hello i have got a little problem i want to read out the followin reg_key

> "hklm\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto
>   Update\"

1. I try this with the example from microsoft:

   ```
   const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
   strComputer = "."
   Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
   Set oReg=GetObject( _
   "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
   strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
   strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl"
   strValueName = "AutoReboot"
   oReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
   WScript.Echo "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\" _
   & "CrashControl\AutoReboot" _
   & " = " & dwValue
   ```
2. Finally changed the keypath "and" value name, when i start the vbs it shown nothing.
3. Here is my code

   ```
   const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
   strComputer = "."
   Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
   Set oReg=GetObject( _
   "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
   strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
   strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\"
   strValueName = "AUOptions"
   oReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
   WScript.Echo "AUOptions: " &dwValue
   ```

can someone help me or give me a tip please ?

Thanks!

Info: OS Win7 x64

Comment: Evaluate the return code of the WMI method (`rc = oReg.GetDWORDValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue)`). What is the value of the variable `rc` after running that statement?

Comment: How is this Windows-Installer related?

Answer (score 0):

That's the difficult way. Even though you don't say what you are doing. Here's an example.

```
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strNamet1=Sh.RegRead("HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOwner")
```

Comment: ok i need a vbs file for another applikation that reads out the winupdate status from this reg_key an make a xml file

("HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\AUoptions")
i try to read out this key by your example like this:

    Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strNamet1=Sh.RegRead("HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\AUoptions")
    WScript.Echo "<UPDATESTATE> & strNamet1 &</UPDATESTATE>"


the output is blank :(